# Why can't we reduce register automata to symbolic automata?

Tags: automata, reduction, automata-theory, boolean-algebra

When considering automata, they are normally considered over finite alphabets. The following are two types of automata that can handle words over infinite alphabets (definitions included for clarity).

The symbols [ and ], appended to the beginning and end of the word respectively, are delimiters and are not in the alphabet. That is, the automata process words of the form *w* = [*v*] where *v* is an element of the alphabet.

A ***k-register automaton*** A over an alphabet is a 5-tuple (Q, q_0, F, t_0, P) where:

- Q is a finite set of states;
- q_0 in Q is the initial (or starting) state;
- F (a subset of Q) is the set of final (or accepting) states;
- t_0 : {0,1,...,k}--> alphabet union {[,]} is the initial register assignment; and,
- P is a finite set of transitions of the form (i, q)-->(q', d) or q-->(q', i, d) for i in {0,1,...,k}, q, q' in Q and d in {Stay, Left, Right}.

A ***symbolic finite automaton (SFA)*** M is a 5-tuple (A, Q, q_0, F, d) where:

- A is an effective Boolean Algebra (the alphabet);
- Q is a finite set of states;
- q_0 in Q is the initial (or starting) state;
- F (a subset of Q) is the set of final (or accepting) states; and,
- d (a subset of Q x Y_A x Q) is a finite set of transitions.

Research has shown that for register automata, equivalence is not decidable but in symbolic automata, it is. My question is why? These two automata types work with similar results, so why is it that we can't reduce one to the other?

Something tells me this is a very simple problem but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, so thank you for any help! :)

My current thoughts are to do with the fact that SFA require their alphabet to be an effective boolean algebra, whereas RA work on anything and so their alphabets dont have to follow the rules of a Boolean algebra. I dont know how to correctly formulate this idea into anything useful though.

Comment: It would make sense to ask this on Computer Science http://cs.stackexchange.com/